# Advice on webserver / database server setup

Tags: virtual-machine, iis, sql-server, home-server, hyper-v

I have a home server (HP ProLiant N36L [link](http://www.amazon.co.uk/HP-Proliant-Microserver-Athlon-N36l/dp/B0043SRUYY#productDescription) with 8Gb of RAM), running Windows Server 2012 that I want to use as a home web server.

Is it worth settings up VM's in Hyper-V for virtual DB servers and web servers? The server will likely never see much traffic, just a couple of hobby sites and a few basic web services.

The setup I had in mind was:

- (Physical) Main_Computer_Name (8Gb RAM)
- (Virtual)  Web_Server (2Gb RAM)
- (Virtual)  DB_Server (2Gb RAM)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Having separate web & database servers will be helpful in keeping your data secure and isolating any bottlenecks.

With 2GB of RAM, your database server will be starved. If the host has 8GB and you're allocating 2GB to each VM, what are you using the remaining 4GB for? If you're using Hyper-V Server, the [following formula](http://blogs.technet.com/b/tonyso/archive/2008/08/12/hyper-v-server-sizing-how-much-memory-for-the-host.aspx) may help you back into the amount of RAM you can allocate to each VM:

```
host RAM (your physical 8GB)  = (VMRamRequirementMB x #ofVMs) + (#ofVMs x 32MBVMOverhead ) + (512MBHost)
```

So you'd be looking at

```
8GB = (X*2) + (X*.032) + 0.512 = 2.544X
X = ~3.14GB RAM per VM
```

Of course, if IIS only needs 2GB RAM, you could bump the database up to a more comfortable 4GB.